# Project objects to array results mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a data set that looks like the one below

```
[{
 _id: ObjectID(),
 data: {
    key1: value,
    key2: value
 }
},
{ 
_id: ObjectId(),
data: {
  key1: value,
  key2: value
}
}]
```

I want to convert the same into

```
[
 [_id,key1,key2], [_id,key1,key2]
]
```

I have tried the aggregation framework but couldn't come up with any way of doing this. I want to avoid looping over the objects if possible but don't know if it would be possible to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing to explain really. Pretty basic [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project : {data : ["$_id", "$data.key1", "$data.key2"]}},
    {$group : {_id : null, result : {$push : "$data"}}}
]);
```